# Unique vs Distinct keyword in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am a bit confused about the uses of these words. I have a table with he following columns: SITE, LAT, LONG, NAME, ......

I want results with unique (or is it distinct) LAT, LONG.
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 11):

```
select unique colA, colB from atable

select distinct colA, colB from atable
```

In this context, unique and distinct mean the same thing.

Distinct however is ANSI standard, whereas unique is not.

Please note that unique has many other meanings when used in other area's ie index creation etc.

Comment: In some flavors of SQL, like "Microsoft SQL", using the UNIQUE keyword there would cause a syntax error.  Always use "DISTINCT".

Answer (score 1):

UNIQUE is used for defining contraints on the data that can be stored in the table.

DISTINCT is used in queries to remove duplicates from the result set, without affecting the underlying table data.

Answer (score 1):

I always like to see a count of how many of each unique item there is so I would:

select lat,long, count(lat) from table group by lat,long   but thats just me

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR both mean the same. To get unique vel distinct LAT & LONG from your table just do:

SELECT DISTINCT LAT, LONG FROM table;