# Difference between SELECT DISTINCT and SELECT UNIQUE

Tags: oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unique vs distinct multi-column in Oracle 9i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174912/unique-vs-distinct-multi-column-in-oracle-9i)

Proper difference between SELECT DISTINCT and SELECT UNIQUE with points and examples.

Answer (score 26):

`SELECT DISTINCT` and `SELECT UNIQUE` behave the same way in oracle.

While `DISTINCT` is ANSI SQL standard, `UNIQUE` is an Oracle specific statement.

Look here: http://psoug.org/definition/DISTINCT.htm

Comment: 2 fast 4 me + 1 for that

Comment: Would be nice to know, why anyone downvoted this again?

Comment: I wonder what Oracle's rationale was for adding UNIQUE

Answer (score 8):

Oracle official documentation

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#sthref9346

States that:

DISTINCT | UNIQUE

Specify DISTINCT or UNIQUE if you want the database to return only one copy of each set of duplicate rows selected. These two keywords are synonymous. Duplicate rows are those with matching values for each expression in the select list.