# count duplicate values in a column sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I want a query to count duplicate values in a column,is there any query for this or i was thinking as

```
total records=SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM table_name;
distinct records=SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) FROM table_name;
duplicate count=total records-distinct records;
```

Comment: Choose one database please don't tag all the available database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your sql, it can be simplified as below :

```
SELECT Count(Column) - Count(DISTINCT Column)
FROM   yourTable
```

Comment: this works perfectly... and i have one more doubt,is distinct count and unique count were same or there is any difference.

Comment: check this question  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772451/difference-between-select-distinct-and-select-unique

Comment: Lot of examples on the web go into unnecessary junction. This one is the shortest an most efficient.

Answer (score 2):

```
select column_name, count(*) 
from table_name 
group by column_name 
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
SELECT COUNT(column_name) as count 
   FROM table_name 
  GROUP BY column_name 
 HAVING count > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much, yes. You can do it in a single query:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(col) FROM tbl) - (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT col) FROM tbl);
```

EDIT: Good point by NoDisplayName. This works in MySQL at least, I don't guarantee cross-engine compatibility (I last worked on Oracle fifteen years ago, and on SQL Server never)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an SQL query, you can take help from a subquery and do something like this:

```
select sum(duplicates) from
(select column_name, num_duplicates-1 as duplicates from
(select column_name,count(column_name) as num_duplicates from table_name
group by column_name
having count(column_name)>1) as table_alias1) as table_alias2
```